# Upload file from AngularJS controller to Spring writtin in Kotlin

Tags: angularjs, spring, kotlin, multipartform-data, form-data

There are a few similar questions already on StackOverflow. I have gone through some of them, but they did not work for me. So please do not mark this question as `duplicate`.

I want to upload a file using AngularJS  to Spring Controller written in Kotlin. I have written the code below in order to do so, but it does not work. I get a `404` bad request response with a message that `Required request part 'file' is not present`

## Input

```html
<form class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-inline " ng-submit="$ctrl.saveFiles()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        Choose File
      </label>
      <input id="file-upload" type="file"  file-model="$ctrl.file" name="file"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

## file-model directive

```js
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

I have copied this directive from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774695/using-multipart-without-form-in-spring-mvc)

## $ctrl.saveFiles() function

```js
    $ctrl.saveFiles = function () {
      // var file = document.getElementById("file-upload").files[0]
      var formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("file", $ctrl.file);

      console.log(formData.has("file"));  // true

      var url = '/upload',
        config = {
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        };
      return $http.post(url, formData, config)
    };
```

## Spring @bean

```js
    @Bean
    open fun multipartResolver(): MultipartResolver {
        val multipartResolver = CommonsMultipartResolver()
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000)
        return multipartResolver
    }
```

## Spring @PostMapping method

```js
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") file: MultipartFile): String {
        return "Upload file"
    }
```

## Request header

```js
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4829202
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryJ8BRhjvMRLt9UdRS
```

As you see though I use `Kotlin`, It is totally fine to answer in `Java`.

Comment: Have you tried using some tool like Postman to POST the endpoint? That way you would know if your problem is client or server related.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. The problem was with the server

Comment: If you fixed it, you should publish the answer as well for readers in the future. Also you might as well change the question and make it only server-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my first time uploading a file using `AngularJS` and `Spring`. There are some who uses [`CommonsMultipartResolver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015891/spring-mvc-angularjs-file-upload-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileuploade). I had done so. However, I did not need to use it.

It was due to using `CommonsMultipartResolver` that I could not upload file. I removed the code below and it works as expected. However, for some reason, I can not upload as large files as an [unsplash photo](https://unsplash.com/photos/w7Z0fiZw4Mw)

```js
@Bean
open fun multipartResolver(): MultipartResolver {
  val multipartResolver = CommonsMultipartResolver()
  multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000)
  return multipartResolver
}
```