# Spring - AngularJS - File Upload - org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am facing the below Exception while uploading a file from angular to my Java Spring MVC web application server

```
<form role="form" name="attachForm" class="form-horizontal" >
        <div class="form-group">
                <input class="col-xs-12" id="uploadFile" type="file" name="uploadFile" file-model ="myFile" ng-disable="closeHidden" required />
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

In my AngularJs

```
var saveFileURL = "caseapi/saveFile";
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', scope.myFile);
return $http.post(saveFileURL,fd,{
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {
                            "Content-Type": undefined
                        }
                });
```

My Directive

```
(function() {
define([ 'appModule'], function(app) {
app.directive('fileModel', [ '$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            console.log("fileModelDir");
            element.bind('change', function() {

                scope.$apply(function() {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
} ]);
});
}).call(this);
```

Server-side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveFile( MultipartFile fd, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    logger.info("SAVE FILE fd : " +fd);
    logger.info("File name :" + fd.getName());
    try 
    {
        /** TODO: Implement file handling **/
        logger.info("saveDraft serviceResponse: ");
        handleResponse(response, serviceResponse);

        logger.info("Exitting saveDraft");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error while calling service: ",ex);
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Below is the Error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [GVEClientExperience] in context 
with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: 
Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was 
rejected because no multipart boundary was found] with root cause
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was 
rejected because no multipart boundary was found
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.
<init>(FileUploadBase.java:990)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:156)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:887)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.ebaysf.web.cors.CORSFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CORSFilter.java:303)
at org.ebaysf.web.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1770)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1729)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have as well refered to this post [Spring MVC - AngularJS - File Upload - org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015891/spring-mvc-angularjs-file-upload-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileuploade)
but it wasnt of help. I am new to Angular. Would like to understand whats wrong here?

Comment: you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671510/multipart-file-upload-using-angularjs-and-springmvc/42717177#42717177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "Content-Type": undefined in the request and data type to consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})

Answer (score 1):

Add the enctype property to your FORM tag.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

Late but could help somebody:

Use [ngFileUpload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload), like this:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (file, param1, param2)
{
    var params ={'param1': param1, 'param2': param2};

    Upload.upload({
        url: 'http://localhost/uploadFile',
        data: {file:file},
        params: params
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    }).catch (function onError(data){
        console.error("Upload pic exception");
        console.error(JSON.stringify(data));
 });;        
};
```

You can also put the parameters inside the data variable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the data type to consume in your controller  and add request param with the key of your file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public void saveFile(@RequestParam(name="fd") MultipartFile fd, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

and no need for contentType:undefined

```
 return $http.post(saveFileURL,fd,{
            transformRequest: angular.identity,

            });
```

and add the encrypt type in your form ad daddygames mentioned

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I am getting the below Exception .  "SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [GVEClientExperience] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]: Specified class is an interface] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]: Specified class is an interface

Comment: what annotation you are using for your controller, and what is the spring version?

Comment: I am using spring 3.2.9

Comment: can you share your full controller

Comment: @Sheetal i edited my answer , check if that solves the issue please, you have RestController annotation on your controller?

Comment: Thats a pretty huge file. I am just using this method in it .                          
saveFile:function(loggedId, supportCase) {
          if ($util.isSet(supportCase)) 
          {var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('file', scope.myFile);
              var saveFileURL = "caseapi/saveFile";
              console.log("SAVE FILE URL : "+ saveFileURL );
              return $http.post(saveFileURL,fd,{
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  
                  });          }
      },

Comment: @Sheetal i want to know which annotation you are using for your controller

Comment: I am using @Controller annotation

Comment: try @RestController

Comment: I tried after the change with @RequestParam(name="fd") but now I am getting a 400 Bad Request error

Comment: try file instead of fd

Comment: oh yes, I meant @RequestParam(name="file") but its throwing 400 Bad Request.  I seem to be lost. Running out of options

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem on your request. Try to do this.

```
return $http.post(saveFileURL,fd,{
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form"
                    }
            });
```

Here is W3C specification mentioning it

> in which one or more different sets of data are combined in a single body, a "multipart" Content-Type field must appear in the entity's header.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this dint help :(

Answer (score 0):

We have managed to deal with such a requirement using simple yet powerful third-party directive [angular-upload](https://github.com/leon/angular-upload). Use is pretty straightforward and simple. More details you can find in documentation.

In HTML page:

```
<div
 class="btn btn-primary btn-upload"
 upload-button
 url="/upload"
 on-success="onSuccess(response)">Upload</div>
```

In Angular Controller:

```
$scope.onSuccess = function(response) {
    // Do something
};
```

In Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadAccessFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // Do something with file
}
```

And finally in your Configuration:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```