# AngularJS: 405 error on uploading multiple images with multipart/form-data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, ngresource

I'm facing **405 error** upon uploading multiple files (images) via multipart/data-form. I'm able to send images in request and seems my **payload** showing correct data (boundaries). But I'm getting empty response 405 on (API) submit and **response.status** is showing 405 (method not allowed) error. I'm wondering what could be wrong as everything seems fine.

However i do suspect that this might be something to do with boundries in **request-payload**. I also come to know that browsers change MIME-TYPE when uploading and this conflicts with multipart/formData.

Please advise what could be wrong. Below is my code.

**Directive** (file-upload)

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

**View** (html)

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="for-param">
    <input type="text" ng-model="for-param">
    <input type="text" ng-model="for-param">

    <input type="file" file-model="image01">
    <input type="file" file-model="image02">

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Controller** (on-submit)

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    var params = {...};
    var data = {
        'frond-side-image' : $scope.image01,
        'back-side-image': $scope.image02
    };

    var formData = new $window.FormData();
    formData.append("image01", $scope.image01);
    formData.append("image02", $scope.image02);

    // Service
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "api-url",
        headers: { "Content-Type": undefined },
        params: params,
        data: formData
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Based on above config I'm getting empty response, but I'm do getting 405 error which is method not allowed.

following is my **Request Headers & Payloads**

**Header Request** (after submit)

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=…--------------147472608521363
```

**Request Payload**

```
-----------------------------1363509831949
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image01"

stacked_circles.png
-----------------------------1363509831949
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image01"

stacked_circles.png
-----------------------------1363509831949--
```

In addition I also have tried to do this with **XMLHttpRequest()** and with that I'm also getting same 405 error with empty response.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', undefined);
request.send(formData);
```

Ref: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015891/spring-mvc-angularjs-file-upload-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileuploade#answer-28303489)

I'm now going to try with $ngResource and see if it can solve my issue.

**Note**: This API is working fine in POSTMAN

**Note**: Backend is in JAVA (spring)

**Note**: later on I'll convert image to base64 to upload on AWS (I'll just post image/base64 to backend than backend will upload it to AWS).

Comment: Does the API support CORS?

Comment: Thanks Musa for response. Yes APIs does support CORS and turns out by pushing this to dev it works as expected.